# getWorkItemRelations() not always return active data

Tags: tfs, azure-devops-rest-api

I have a custom control that shows the hyperlinks related to the active Work item. To do this, I call the [getWorkItemRelations()](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/reference/client/api/tfs/workitemtracking/services/workitemformservice#method_getWorkItemRelations) and almost always works fine. My problem is when I delete a Link and the refresh in my custom control is called the result array includes the deleted "Links". In the Link tab the deleted Link was removed.

I review the resulting array for a flag that indicates if the Link was deleted but it doesn't exists.

Also, I put a button to refresh the data in my custom control but the result is the same.

Are there a way that I can force to full reload the relationships for the Work Item?

Comment: Hi, sorry to say that not solved my issue. Thanks.

Comment: Did you click Save button after remove the link?

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT, yes. I clicked the save button and the Custom Control get refreshed as expected. But I can't save the WI for each time the user delete a Link because I will generate an unnecessary revision of WI.

Answer (score 0):

This phenomenon maybe related to the data caches on client computers. You could give a try with refresh the Work Item Cache.

> To update the cache for tracking work items, you invoke the
>   **StampWorkitemCache** Web method. This method forces client computers to update the cache the next time that they connect to the
>   application-tier server. This method also synchronizes the workspaces
>   that are defined on the client computers.

To refresh the cache for tracking work items on client computers:

1. On the new server, open Internet Explorer.
2. In the Address bar, enter the following address to connect to the
   **ClientService** web service:

   ```
   http:// PublicURL/VirtualDirectory :8080/WorkItemTracking/v3.0/ClientService.asmx
   ```
3. Choose **StampWorkitemCache**, and then choose **Invoke**.

***Note:*** To invoke the **StampWorkitemCache** Web method, you must be a member of the **Administrators** security group on the application-tier server for Team Foundation.

More details info about the method please refer the official documentation: [Refresh the Work Item Cache](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/tfs/admin/backup/refresh-data-caches#refresh-the-work-item-cache)

---

**Update**

Every changes on the work item need to be saved. Unlike  UI on the web,it's not a real-time display. You need to save the work item , then refresh  in your custom control .

Comment: Thanks for you answer. But it didn't resolve my issue because i'm using VSO and can't invoke the WebService. What I see, debugging a bit, is that the method internally retains the removed items until it is flushed when save the work item.

Comment: @sGambolati Yes, it's the root cause. Every changes on the work item need to be saved. Unlike  UI on the web,it's not a real-time display. You need to save the work item , then refresh  in your custom control .